# how to define dynamic headers in Azure custom connector template

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-logic-apps, openapi

The header parameters in the logicApp template can be added multiple times dynamically, but i want the same functionality in my custom connector template. I cannot find any tutorial or docs to do so. [image]

This is my custom connector, here i can have multiple fields,but i want it similar to a key value pair table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently supported on the designer view. But you can do it in the code view and add them there:

```
"headers": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
}
```

HTH

Comment: Its not dynamic actually ,if we are doing from the code , i need it to be an input from the user

Comment: you could set the headers value to a variable's value, or the output of a previous action, and make it dynamic.

Comment: I can't get you. could you give a piece of example ? What i need is the fields like that shown in the connector.

Comment: Sorry @HariHaran, not sure what you are after. As I mentioned, you could use the code view to set the value of headers in custom connectors using a key/value pair object at design time. If required at run-time, you could set the headers property to a variable or the output of a previous action.